# Invoking share charm programatically in a Unity game

Tags: windows-phone-8, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

I am developing a game for windows store/phone using Unity 4.6 and want to share score on facebook and other platforms using share charm. I have a button in my scene but I am unable to invoke share charm through it programatically. I tried using

```
DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
```

but it gives me following error:

```
activating a single-threaded class from mta is not supported
```

Can anyone tell me how can I achieve my desired functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Windows Store (including Windows Phone 8.1 Runtime) app you can use the [UnityEngine.WSA.Application](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WSA.Application.html)'s [InvokeOnUIThread](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread.html) or [TryInvokeOnUIThread](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WSA.Application.TryInvokeOnUIThread.html) methods to call a delegate on the UI Thread from which you can call Windows Runtime UI methods such as ShowShareUI:

```
public void OnClick()
{
    UnityEngine.WSA.Application.InvokeOnUIThread(() =>
    {
        Debug.Log("On UI Thread");
#if NETFX_CORE
        Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.DataTransferManager.ShowShareUI();
#endif
    }, false);
}
```

If you're specifically targeting Windows Phone 8 you probably need a plug-in to marshal to the UI thread since UnityEngine.WSA is not available.